# Singular sdk deep link not working on flutter iOS

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, deep-linking, singular

I am using singular_flutter_sdk: ^1.0.12 for deep link in my flutter application , in android its working fine but in iOS, when application is already running in background it works but when application is initialised by tapping on the link it only works for first time and when I tap again  on link it opens the applications from the background and does not navigate to specific screen .

it should navigate to screen every time when initialising the app using link

### AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import singular_flutter_sdk

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
    override func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?)
    -> Bool {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
        if let singularAppDelegate = SingularAppDelegate.shared() {
            singularAppDelegate.launchOptions = launchOptions
        }
        return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }

    override func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
        if let singularAppDelegate = SingularAppDelegate.shared() {
            singularAppDelegate.continueUserActivity(userActivity, restorationHandler: nil)
        }
        return true
    }

    override func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        if let singularAppDelegate = SingularAppDelegate.shared() {
            singularAppDelegate.handleOpen(url, options: options)
        }
        return true
    }

}
```

### main.dart

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with WidgetsBindingObserver {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    SingularConfig config = SingularConfig(singularApiKey, singularApiSecret);
    config.singularLinksHandler = ((SingularLinkParams params) {
      String? deeplink = params.deeplink;
      String? passthrough = params.passthrough;
      bool? isDeferred = params.isDeferred;
      // Add your code here to handle the deep link
    });
    config.waitForTrackingAuthorizationWithTimeoutInterval = 60;
    config.skAdNetworkEnabled = true;
    config.clipboardAttribution = true;
    Singular.event("Launched");
    Singular.event("Completed");
    Singular.start(config);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          home: const SplashScreen(),
        );
  } 
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Hamed added the code snippet

Comment: @YugalKalyan have you find a way yo make it works?

Answer (score 0):

Did you register your sigular link domain into your iOS project?
Check `Xcode > Targets > Signing&Capabilities>Associated Domains`.

The following guides are from the Singular documentation:(https://support.singular.net/hc/en-us/articles/12054824479387--UPDATED-iOS-SDK-Integration-Guide)

1. Followed the instructions in https://support.singular.net/hc/en-us/articles/360031371451-Singular-Links-Prerequisites
2. In Xcode, added a Singular Custom Subdomain to Signing & Capabilities > Associated Domains.
3. Added the app scheme to your URL Types at Info > URL Types.
4. Added your Apple Developer Team ID and Scheme in the Apps page in the Singular web app.